# How do I serialize instance of object to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Here is my code:

```
public class DataClass
{
   private string member = string.Empty;
   public string Member
   {
      get
      {
         return member;
      }
   }

   private DataClass() { }
   public DataClass(string memberToSet) 
   {
      this.member = memberToSet;
   }

   public string SerializeXML()
   {
      XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

      var xml = "";

      using (var sww = new StringWriter())
      {
         using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
         {
            xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, this);
            xml = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
         }
      }

      return xml;
   }
}
```

I've done this with an external method and it works.  Is there some restriction to using `this`?  Here is my result which does not serialize any properties in my object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><DataClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

Comment: How are you setting the value of the property?

Comment: `The Serialize method converts the public fields and read/write properties of an object into XML. It does not convert methods, indexers, private fields, or read-only properties. To serialize all of an object's fields and properties, both public and private, use the BinaryFormatter.` - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552(v=vs.110).aspx). I think @MongZhu's solution of including a setter is the only way.

Comment: You can "trick" it by creating a setter which doesn't actually assign the value: `public string Member {get {return member;} set {return;}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `Member` property a setter. Try this :

```
public class DataClass
{
    public string Member { get; set; }

    public DataClass(string memberToSet)
    {
        this.Member = memberToSet;
    }
...
```

And your result will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><DataClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Member>asd</Member></DataClass>
```

> Is there some restriction to using `this`?

not that I know of. It depends more on the accessibility of properties

Comment: @sab669 you are correct, it does have a value.  This is "a" solution but hopefully this is not the only way as it was not an accident for me to not have a setter.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a private setter.  It is an understandable restriction to XML serialization as you will not be able to deserialize xml to a `DataClass` object without a setter.  The reason for the design rather than using something like a copy constructor, is because the deserialize process copies one member at a time.  If it tried to hold all of the data and use a copy constructor, it could potentially need to hold some huge object in memory.

Credit to @MongZhu for helping me realize this.